# Segments in a circle using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I know you can make a circle in CSS using the border radius hack. But is there any way to make them have segments like this picture? Is there a way of doing this through HTML and CSS but not JS?

[image]

Comment: You could do it with little elements and CSS rotation transformations, but that seems pretty painful.

Comment: Mr. Pointy please tell me how...I really want to know! :) Pwetty please with sugar lumps on top! :)

Comment: Well I'm not a CSS transform expert, but you'd basically make `<div>` elements (or whatever) that would be styled as short line segments, and then you'd rotate & translate them into a circle. It's just analytical geometry practice :-) [Here is the MDN page about what transforms can do.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform)

Comment: Oh wait - are you asking about how to draw radial line segments *inside* the circle?  If so, I completely misunderstood; I thought you were trying to draw the circle itself.

Comment: Yes, segments inside the circle. That is what I wanted. Was my diagram misleading? I want each segment to highlight when hovered over too.

Comment: That might be possible, but it's probably pretty tricky.  Possibly using a `<canvas>` or SVG would be easier; you're going to have cross-browser issues no matter how you approach it, I suspect.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, you can get such slices of custom angles using either one of the following two methods:

1. If you don't need the slices to be elements themselves, the you can simply do it with one element and linear gradients - see this [**rainbow wheel**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/hkxGp) I did last month.
2. If you need the slices to be elements themselves, then you can do it by chaining rotate and skew transforms - see this [**circular menu**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3912488) I did a while ago.

For #2, see also this very much simplified [**example**](http://dabblet.com/gist/4469797) I did right now.

```css
.pie {
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: dashed 1px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 32em; height: 32em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}
.slice {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  width: 50%; height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%; 
}
.slice:first-child {
  transform: rotate(15deg) skewY(-22.5deg);
}
.slice-contents {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%; height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.slice:first-child .slice-contents {
  transform: skewY(22.5deg); /* unskew slice contents */
}
.slice:hover .slice-contents { background: violet; } /* highlight on hover */
```

```html
<ul class='pie'>
  <li class='slice'>
    <div class='slice-contents'></div>
  </li>
  <!-- you can add more slices here -->
</ul>
```

Comment: the circular menu disappeared :(

Comment: @Adam  probably a similar dabblet showing how the idea works http://dabblet.com/gist/5020696 ... probably late comment, but did not see it before now ;) could be looking like citrus too https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/wutEK

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can: http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/3rx7w/, http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/3rx7w/2/

```css
#chart {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 60px solid purple;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
```

```css
.chart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
}

#chart1 {
  border-right: 60px solid red;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}

#chart2 {
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid green;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}

#chart3 {
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}

#chart4 {
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart1" class="chart"></div>
<div id="chart2" class="chart"></div>
<div id="chart3" class="chart"></div>
<div id="chart4" class="chart"></div>
```

Source: http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css

Answer (score 7):

You can use html `li` element and some css `transform` to represent each slice of the circle.

The tricky part is the `transform`. In this case I've divided the circle into 5 slices.
The calculation is the following.
`360/5=72 -> rotate`
`72+90=162 -> skewY`

```css
.sliceWrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slice {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}

li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

li:first-child {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(162deg);
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(72deg) skewY(162deg);
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(144deg) skewY(162deg);
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(216deg) skewY(162deg);
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(288deg) skewY(162deg);
}

li:first-child .slice {
  background: green;
}

li:nth-child(2) .slice {
  background: tomato;
}

li:nth-child(3) .slice {
  background: aqua;
}

li:nth-child(4) .slice {
  background: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(5) .slice {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sliceWrapper">
  <li>
    <div class="slice"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slice"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slice"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slice"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="slice"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems to repeat Ana's answer from 6 years prior.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a conic gradient

Conic gradients basically go around the shape, like a circle, from 0° to 360°.

Here is a basic conic gradient, with a circle:

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    background: red; /* fallback */
    background: conic-gradient(red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Using color stops, we can then, magically, turn it into segments:

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    background: red; /* fallback */
    background: conic-gradient(red 10%, orange 10%, orange 30%, yellow 30%, yellow 50%, green 50%, green 60%, blue 60%, blue 70%, purple 70%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Optionally, if we only want one slice, we can now change this so we only have one colour, and now we're good to go :)

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    background: red; /* fallback */
    background: conic-gradient(#0000 40%, red 40%, red 70%, #0000 70%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {

  --skew: 30deg;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper .sector {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 5000px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin-top: -5000px;
  margin-left: -5000px;
}
.wrapper .sector:hover {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sector" style="transform: rotate(0deg) skew(var(--skew));"></div>
        <div class="sector" style="transform: rotate(60deg) skew(var(--skew));"></div>
        <div class="sector" style="transform: rotate(120deg) skew(var(--skew));"></div>
        <div class="sector" style="transform: rotate(180deg) skew(var(--skew));"></div>
        <div class="sector" style="transform: rotate(240deg) skew(var(--skew));"></div>
        <div class="sector" style="transform: rotate(300deg) skew(var(--skew));"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is possible to set the number of slices by calculating div tags and angles.

for 6 slices
--skew:30deg;

And the interior angle of a circle is 360 degrees. If it's 6 pieces, divide by 6 to find the beginning of each slice. That means 0-60-120-180-240-300 values. If you are going to divide by 8, the values will come out accordingly and you should also revise the --skew value.

Comment: This repeats the solution from the top answer from 2013. And at least one other one.