# How to create a sliced circle using CSS3/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me to create a sliced circle where i can click on each slice to give different commands, like we do in buttons. The slices must be like follows:

- 2 Circles, Main Outer circle, inner circle (half sized as outer circle),
- 3 Lines over main circle where it devides the 2 circles into 12 slices.
  The straight line from those 3 lines should be the vertical line.

Reference Image:

[image: circle with slices]

```css
.maincircle {
  height: 404px;
  width: 404px;
}

.slice1 {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #093;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 190px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 190px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 190px 0 0 0;
}

.slice1:hover {
  background-color: #6C6;
}

.slice2 {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #093;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 190px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 190px 0 0;
}

.slice2:hover {
  background-color: #6C6;
}

.slice3 {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #093;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 190px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 190px;
}

.slice3:hover {
  background-color: #6C6;
}

.slice4 {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #093;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 190px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 190px 0;
}

.slice4:hover {
  background-color: #6C6;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincircle">
  <div class="slice1"></div>
  <div class="slice2"></div>
  <div class="slice3"></div>
  <div class="slice4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into the `<svg>` or `<canvas>` elements. If you don't need to add any elaborate animations, `<svg>` will be the best for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segments in a circle using CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184494/segments-in-a-circle-using-css3)

Comment: I could only do upto the level where i used 4 divs, where it only has 4 slices,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick example of the approach I would take

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/XN3ZB/314/

I use `http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js` for things like this. It means using a pie chart, you can style them to suit your needs and get them to behave how you like. It is very quick and simple.

EDITED

Updated to multilayer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#2a6705']
  });

  RenderPieChart('container', [
    ['one piece', 15.6],
    ['one piece', 15.6],
    ['one piece', 15.6],
    ['one piece', 15.6],
    ['one piece', 15.6],
    ['one piece', 15.6],
  ]);

  function RenderPieChart(elementId, dataList) {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: elementId,
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Use a pie chart for more than just data'
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {

          return '<b> Add an event here</b>';

        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            connectorColor: '#000000',
            formatter: function() {
              return '<b>Make these clickable</b>';
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: dataList
      }, {
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: dataList,
        innerSize: '70%'
      }]
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: If you do not need it interactive, only clickable, i'd simply suggest an image with a `html` image map

Answer (score 5):

I found this interesting, so I went ahead and created it in SVG:

```css
path:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg height="440px" width="440px">
  <path d="M 220 220 L 270 306.60254037844385 A 100 100 0 0 0 320 220 z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('inner-0')" />
  <path d="M 420 220 A 200 200 0 0 1 320 393.2050807568877  L 270 306.60254037844385 A 100 100 0 0 0 320 220  z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('outer-0')" />
  <path d="M 220 220 L 170.00000000000003 306.6025403784439 A 100 100 0 0 0 270 306.60254037844385 z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('inner-1')" />
  <path d="M 320 393.2050807568877 A 200 200 0 0 1 120.00000000000004 393.20508075688775  L 170.00000000000003 306.6025403784439 A 100 100 0 0 0 270 306.60254037844385  z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('outer-1')" />
  <path d="M 220 220 L 120 220 A 100 100 0 0 0 170.00000000000003 306.6025403784439 z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('inner-2')" />
  <path d="M 120.00000000000004 393.20508075688775 A 200 200 0 0 1 20 220.00000000000003  L 120 220 A 100 100 0 0 0 170.00000000000003 306.6025403784439  z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('outer-2')" />
  <path d="M 220 220 L 169.99999999999994 133.39745962155615 A 100 100 0 0 0 120 220 z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('inner-3')" />
  <path d="M 20 220.00000000000003 A 200 200 0 0 1 119.99999999999991 46.79491924311233  L 169.99999999999994 133.39745962155615 A 100 100 0 0 0 120 220  z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('outer-3')" />
  <path d="M 220 220 L 269.99999999999994 133.3974596215561 A 100 100 0 0 0 169.99999999999994 133.39745962155615 z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('inner-4')" />
  <path d="M 119.99999999999991 46.79491924311233 A 200 200 0 0 1 319.9999999999999 46.79491924311219  L 269.99999999999994 133.3974596215561 A 100 100 0 0 0 169.99999999999994 133.39745962155615  z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('outer-4')"
  />
  <path d="M 220 220 L 320 219.99999999999997 A 100 100 0 0 0 269.99999999999994 133.3974596215561 z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('inner-5')" />
  <path d="M 319.9999999999999 46.79491924311219 A 200 200 0 0 1 420 219.99999999999994  L 320 219.99999999999997 A 100 100 0 0 0 269.99999999999994 133.3974596215561  z" fill="green" stroke="white" onclick="alert('outer-5')" />
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2h4J/2/

In case anyone's interested, I generated this with the following (ugly) code:

```js
var RADIUS = 200;
var PADDING = 20;
var SLICES = 6;

var svg = "";

for (var i = 0; i < SLICES; i++) {
  var p1 = {
    x: Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * i) * RADIUS + RADIUS + PADDING,
    y: Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * i) * RADIUS + RADIUS + PADDING
  };

  var p2 = {
    x: Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * (i + 1)) * RADIUS + RADIUS + PADDING,
    y: Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * (i + 1)) * RADIUS + RADIUS + PADDING
  };

  var p4 = {
    x: Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * i) * (RADIUS / 2) + RADIUS + PADDING,
    y: Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * i) * (RADIUS / 2) + RADIUS + PADDING
  };

  var p3 = {
    x: Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * (i + 1)) * (RADIUS / 2) + RADIUS + PADDING,
    y: Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / SLICES * (i + 1)) * (RADIUS / 2) + RADIUS + PADDING
  };


  svg += "<path d='M " + (RADIUS + PADDING) + " " + (RADIUS + PADDING) + " L " + p3.x + " " + p3.y + " A " + (RADIUS / 2) + " " + (RADIUS / 2) + " 0 0 0 " + p4.x + " " + p4.y + " z' fill='green' stroke='white' onclick='alert(\"inner-" + i + "\")'/>";

  svg += "<path d='M " + p1.x + " " + p1.y + " A " + RADIUS + " " + RADIUS + " 0 0 1 " + p2.x + " " + p2.y + "  L " + p3.x + " " + p3.y + " A " + RADIUS / 2 + " " + RADIUS / 2 + " 0 0 0 " + p4.x + " " + p4.y + "  z' fill='green' stroke='white' onclick='alert(\"outer-" + i + "\")'/>";
}

svg = "<svg height='" + (RADIUS * 2 + PADDING * 2) + "px' width='" + (RADIUS * 2 + PADDING * 2) + "px'>" + svg + "</svg>";

$("body").append(svg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3pLn/1/

Comment: @James: I am new to SVG and like your idea of slicing the circle. Is it possible to put the text on each slice on the slices. I am trying to achieve Org Chart of 2 or 3 levels . with Parent at the center i.e innermost circle and its children around it and when click on a children then that will be parent and outer circle would have its children.

Comment: @JDev You can put text on the svg.  Have a look at the `<text>` element.  Unfortunately text in svg doesn't have wrapping and things like that, so it can be tricky if the text is dynamic.

Comment: oh. texts are going to be dynamic for each node.