# Creating a heavily segmented ring/circle

Tags: css, svg, raphael, visualization, graphael

[image]

I need to recreate the above image using HTML, CSS, SVG, or some other similar means. It'll be solely for visual purposes, not needing any type of actual functionality. Preferably the non-white parts would be transparent so that I could easily change the background color and have other elements within the center

The reason why I cannot use a transparent image is because I need to be able to easily scale it and possibly change the color of the bars with little trouble

I know how to do approximately the same thing using [this CSS approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184494/segments-in-a-circle-using-css3), but that would require a separate element for every single segment which I do not want.

The other option I thought up would be to create a doughnut graph in Raphael.js with a whole lot pieces in it, but that also seems like a lot of work for the simple outcome that I want

So before I start a long and complex process using one of the methods I mentioned, is there a simpler, more optimized way to create the effect I desire? I'm not asking for the finished output, merely insight as to what methods are optimal to create this type of effect

**Edit**

The optimal solution would be a pure CSS approach that does not require a separate element for each segment. Otherwise the answers provided are great solutions!

Comment: If it's supposed to be large on the page, I think that a simple loop in Raphael would be the easiest and efficient solution. I'd go with plain Raphael there, without any chart library that would add unnecessary overhead. On the other hand, if this will be a rather small image, perhaps canvas would be a better approach.

Of course, that's in assumption that you don't want separate nodes due to performance reasons. From coding point of view, the loop needed to create those slices can be very simple.

Comment: @HubertOG I suppose I should have included this in the question, but my end goal is recreating [this gif](http://25.media.tumblr.com/80e9f362624c435671009ae1144b2b30/tumblr_mt1dwzLkWu1s1b7oqo1_400.gif) (optimally it'd use pure CSS). So far, [this is what I have](http://cssdeck.com/labs/gif-recreation). I suppose I'll try both using canvas and restricting myself to the current size using a transparent image. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do this with `stroke-dasharray`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-dasharray="0.628" stroke-width="2" 
            fill="none" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/75WsM/

Comment: Is there any way I could load the SVG through CSS without placing an SVG element or using javascript? In other words could I load it through a `:after` pseudoelement? I don't believe there is but then again I didn't know about `stroke-dasharray` either

Comment: You could use it as a background-image

Comment: One note for anyone who looks at this in the future: I had to include `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` in my svg tag and use base64 encoding for it to work properly

Answer (score 1):

Easy loop should be enough.

```
<div id="R">
</div>

<script>
var createCircle = function(step,posX,posY,radius){
    var paper = Raphael("R",500,500);
    for(var i = 0; i < 360; i=i+step){        
        var currentRect = paper.rect(posX+radius,posY, 2,20);
        currentRect.attr({'fill':'#ffffff',stroke:0});
        currentRect.rotate(i,posX+radius,posY + radius);
    }
}
createCircle(3,50,50,94);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBKP4/2/