# Wheel of Luck: Select Appropriate DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need one other Help in Wheel of Luck Game. I need TO select 3 DIVs among 6 divs. but what happen if i Select div as shown in Below images it will select 6 No DIV instead of 5 or 1 Respectively. I have used code in below snippet.

[image]

```js
// replacement for localStorage to get snippet working
localStorageX = {
  dic: {},
  setItem: function(key, val) {
    localStorageX.dic[key] = val;
  },
  getItem: function(key) {
    return localStorageX.dic[key];
  },
}

//set default degree (360*5)
var degree = 1800;
//number of clicks = 0
var clicks = 0,
        is_spinning = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    /*WHEEL SPIN FUNCTION*/
    $('#spin').click(function () {
        //add 1 every click
        if (is_spinning) {

            return false;
        }
        ;
        is_spinning = 1;
        clicks++;

        /*multiply the degree by number of clicks
         generate random number between 1 - 360,
         then add to the new degree*/
        var newDegree = degree * clicks;
        var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        totalDegree = newDegree + extraDegree;

        var win_num = 6 - Math.floor((totalDegree % 360 + 30) / 60);

        /*let's make the spin btn to tilt every
         time the edge of the section hits
         the indicator*/
        $('#wheel .sec').each(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;

            var interval = parseInt(t.data('interval'));
            if (interval > 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                t.data('interval', '');
            }

            t.data('interval', setInterval(function () {

                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(t.html());
                console.log(aoY);

                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that
                 each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                 So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                 that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore,
                 exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if (aoY < 23.89) {
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);
                }
            }, 10));

            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform': 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'
            });

            noY = t.offset().top;

        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#wheel .sec').each(function () {
                var t = $(this);
                var interval = parseInt(t.data('interval'));
                if (interval > 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    t.data('interval', '');
                }
            });
            $("#txt").html($('#wheel div.sec:nth-child(' + win_num + ')').html());
        }, 6100);
        $("#spin_disable").removeClass("disable");
    });
    obj = [];
    localStorageX.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(obj));
    var inc = 1;
    $('#wheel .sec').click(function (e)
    {
        var obbj = $(this);
        var selected  = localStorageX.getItem("selected");

        var obj = [];
        if(selected){
            obj= JSON.parse(selected);  
        }
        var SelectedNumber = obbj[0].textContent;
        var compare = $.inArray( SelectedNumber, obj);
        if(compare < 0){
            if(obj.length <= 2){
                $(this).addClass('myApp');
                if (obj.length == 3)
                {
                    $("#spin_disable").addClass("disable");
                }
                obj.push(SelectedNumber);
                localStorageX.setItem("selected",JSON.stringify(obj)); 
            }else{
                alert("3 selected");
            }
        }else{
            var removeItem = obbj[0].textContent;
            obj = jQuery.grep(obj, function(value) {
              return value != removeItem;
            });
            $(this).removeClass('myApp');
            localStorageX.setItem("selected",JSON.stringify(obj));
        }
    });
});//DOCUMENT READY
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

body{
    background:#eaeaea;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

a{
    color:#34495e;
}




/*WRAPPER*/
#wrapper{
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    width:266px;
    position:relative;
}

#txt{
    color:#000;
}


/*WHEEL*/
#wheel{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:8px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 0px 10px, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0px 3px 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#wheel:before{
    content:'';
    position:relative;
    /* border:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
    width:242px;
    height:242px;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:1000;
}

#inner-wheel{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    -webkit-transition: all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -moz-transition:    all 6 cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -o-transition:      all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -ms-transition:     all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    transition:         all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
}

#wheel div.sec{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 130px 70px 0;
    border-color: #19c transparent;
    transform-origin: 75px 129px;
    left:50px;
    top:-4px;
    opacity:1;
}

#wheel div.sec:nth-child(1){
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    border-color: #d4d4d4 transparent;
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
    border-color: #d4d4d4 transparent;
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-color: #d4d4d4 transparent;
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(4){
    transform: rotate(240deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
    border-color: #d4d4d4 transparent;
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(5){
    transform: rotate(300deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
    border-color: #d4d4d4 transparent;
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(6){
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-color: #d4d4d4 transparent;
}


#wheel div.sec .fa{
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:36px;
    margin-left:-15px;

    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px -1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 0px;
}






#spin{
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-34px 0 0 -34px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 3px 0px;
    z-index:1000;
    background:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


#spin:after{
    content:"SPIN";
    text-align:center;
    line-height:68px;
    color:#CCC;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    display:block;
}

#spin:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 20px 28px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
    top:-12px;
    left:14px;
}

#inner-spin{
    width:54px;
    height:54px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-27px 0 0 -27px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:red;
    z-index:999;
    box-shadow:rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px -2px 0px inset, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 2px 0px inset,  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px ;

    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(234,234,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

#spin:active #inner-spin{
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px inset;
}

#spin:active:after{
    font-size:15px;
}



#shine{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99)), color-stop(9%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */


    opacity:0.1;

}



/*ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes hh {
    0%, 100%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    50%{
        transform: rotate(7deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    }
}

@keyframes hh {
    0%, 100%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    50%{
        transform: rotate(7deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    }
}

.spin {
    -webkit-animation: hh 0.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: hh 0.1s;
}
.myApp{
    border-color: blue transparent !important;
}
#spin_disable  {  background: none;

                  border-radius: 50%;
                  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                  cursor: pointer;
                  font-family: "Exo 2",sans-serif;
                  height: 68px;
                  left: 50%;
                  margin: -34px 0 0 -34px;
                  opacity: 1;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  width: 68px;
                  z-index: 1001;}

#spin_disable.disable  { z-index:-111;}
```

```html
<head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      
    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="wheel">
                <div id="inner-wheel">
                    <div class="sec" value="1"><span class="fa fa-bell-o"></span><span>1</span></div>
                    <div class="sec" value="2"><span class="fa fa-comment-o"></span><span>2</span></div>
                    <div class="sec" value="3"><span class="fa fa-smile-o"></span><span>3</span></div>
                    <div class="sec" value="4"><span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span><span>4</span></div>
                    <div class="sec" value="5"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span><span>5</span></div>
                    <div class="sec" value="6"><span class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></span><span>6</span></div>
                    <div id="spin_disable"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="spin">
                    <div id="inner-spin"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="shine"></div>
            </div>


            <div id="txt"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segments in a circle using CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184494/segments-in-a-circle-using-css3)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `div`, or any other element which is square in nature, you should use an image map with 6 areas so you don't get any overlapping:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Here's a helpful tool you can use to create one:

https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html

Example (hover over 1 or 6):

```css
area {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 24, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksl2d.png" alt="" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="194, 27, 217, 43, 232, 59, 243, 76, 252, 97, 258, 126, 167, 129, 162, 114, 155, 108, 149, 103" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="71, 27, 91, 17, 120, 10, 148, 9, 180, 16, 188, 20, 145, 102, 132, 98, 123, 101, 113, 107" />
</map>
```

For yours, you could then replace the image with a transparent `png`, and then map the area clicks to affect the relevant element.