# Create Circle with 3 parts and perform action from each part in HTML/css/script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to design UI in html. I have a requirement to design as per the referenced image. I required source code for the same design. Please do the needful.

There are 3 part in a circle. There will be an event while clicking each part.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8QaA3VryqygYU9valJoYm9WSEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hope this would be helpful http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/hwpa0uk1/9/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Sahana. To get the best help possible please go to the [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page where you can see how to ask questions accepted by the community.

Comment: thank you sasi!. it would be really helpful if I get closure design.+

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create such a segmented circle in CSS. First, you create the circle with `border-radius: 50%;` on the container element. Than you create your segments with `transform`:

```
transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg) scale(1.2);
```

Explanation: With `rotate` you can place each segment on its proper place, with `skew` you create the needed angle for the circle center and with `scale` you make sure that the segments fill the circle up to the border. At last you just create an element for the inner circle and you are done.

To make the segments clickable, you can use the `onclick` event handler or jQuerys `click()` function.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184494/segments-in-a-circle-using-css3).

```css
.pie {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slice {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.slice-contents {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.slice:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg) scale(1.2);
}
.slice:nth-child(1) .slice-contents {
  transform: skewY(-30deg); /* unskew slice contents */
    background: lightblue;
}
.slice:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(30deg) scale(1.2);
}
.slice:nth-child(2) .slice-contents {
  transform: skewY(-30deg); /* unskew slice contents */
    background: lightgreen;
}
.slice:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(30deg) scale(1.2);
}
.slice:nth-child(3) .slice-contents {
  transform: skewY(-30deg); /* unskew slice contents */
    background: orange;
}
.inner-pie {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class='pie'>
  <li class='slice'>
    <div class='slice-contents'>click 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class='slice'>
    <div class='slice-contents'>click 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class='slice'>
    <div class='slice-contents'>click 3</div>
  </li>
  <li class='inner-pie'>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: I was trying to display the text horizontally. but it did not comes correctly. Can you help on this. eg. slice-contents content should show like TOP on the first slice, LEFT and RIGHT on the 2nd and 3rd slice. Also want to raise a click event which should click within the pie circle but no action out of the boundary.

Comment: @Sahana Glad I could help. I would apreciate an upvote/accept :) For the problem mentioned in your comment above simply ask another question.