# CSS Semicircle with segments

Tags: html, css, less, css-shapes

I am trying to create a semicircle with 5 segments, as shown in the image below, where I can easily adjust the spacing between various segments and the size of the segments themselves.

CSS Semicircle Example

[image]

I'm very much a novice at frontend development, but I have tried several resources, so as to figure this out on my own before coming here:

1. [Building a Circular Navigation with CSS Transforms](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/)
2. [Segments in a circle using CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184494/segments-in-a-circle-using-css3)
3. A ton of codepen pens.

I need help with a simple and pure CSS solution that doesn't involve working with a crazy ton of math by way of mixins or rolling a SVG solution.

Any help would be appreciated... I've been at this for 3 days and this is pretty much a last resort.

Comment: Another note: I looked at linear gradients, but I much prefer individual elements.

Comment: do the segments need to be different colours?

Comment: Negative. They do not need to be different colors, but that shouldn't matter when it comes to code.

You can freely apply 'color' (LESS) or 'background' to each element that is outputted through the HTML from CSS.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've taken this from a previous answer and modified it a bit to get it into the right sort of shape.

The spacing between each segment will be difficult without using something like SVG because of the limitations that CSS has.

It's not perfect and it will be difficult to make it perfect with just pure CSS.

```css
.wheel,
.umbrella,
.color {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wheel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  padding: 3px;
}
.umbrella {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.color,
.color:nth-child(n+7):after {
  clip: rect(0, 15em, 15em, 7.5em);
}
.color:after,
.color:nth-child(n+7) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  top: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  clip: rect(0, 7.5em, 15em, 0);
}
.color:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #9ED110;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 12;
}
.color:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #50B517;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 11;
}
.color:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #179067;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 10;
}
.color:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #476EAF;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 9;
}
.color:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #9f49ac;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  z-index: 8;
}
.color:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #CC42A2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wheel">
  <ul class="umbrella">
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

An alternative would be to make a single SVG shape which is then referenced as a clip-path in CSS. The above code would stay pretty much the exact same, it would just be the change of how the shape is generated.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it is possible without the use of SVG and clip path, as shown in the first item I used to try to accomplish this. I debated on rolling a SVG solution because I can simply design it in AI and roll it out in the HTML.

I'm trying to do something with straight up CSS because WordPress doesn't play nice with SVGs - including various security issues.

Comment: actually, "rect" is not widely support, you would have to come up with a polyfil